# Mysql - Unique constraint on CAST(TIMESTAMP as DATE)

Tags: mysql, sql, unique-constraint

I have a `TIMESTAMP myDate` field in my MYSQL Table.

Is there a way I can define a unique string `stringForTheDay` for every *day* in `myDate`?

Something like:

```
UNIQUE(stringForTheDay, day_in_mydate)
```

In short, these 2 rows must not be allowed:

```
2012-11-29 13:35:53      samestring
2012-11-29 20:39:09      samestring
```

Comment: Can you not use DATE instead of TIMESTAMP?

Answer (score 3):

I think your best bet is to copy the date-part into a separate column, and add a unique constraint on it. You can keep the date-part up-to-date by using triggers:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ins_tablename BEFORE INSERT ON tablename
FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.dateColumn = CAST(NEW.timestampColumn AS DATE);

CREATE TRIGGER upd_tablename BEFORE UPDATE ON tablename
FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.dateColumn = CAST(NEW.timestampColumn AS DATE);
```

(See [§18.3 "Using Triggers" in the *MySQL 5.6 Reference Manual*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/triggers.html).)

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

Alternatively, you can create another column which has a data type of `DATE` only and make a unique compound key with your dateOnly column and the string column,

eg

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
(
  `day_in_mydate` datetime, 
  `stringForTheDay` varchar(10),
  `dateControl` date,
  UNIQUE (dateControl, stringForTheDay)
)
```

a full example was demonstrated here,

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/75154/1)

if you have an existing table with records on it, but you can still alter it. Add a column with `DATE` datatype, and execute this query

```
ALTER TABLE tableName ADD CONSTRAINT tb_UQ UNIQUE (dateOnlyColumn, stringColumn)
```

and update the table with its value from the timestamp field.

```
UPDATE tableName
SET    dateOnlyColumn = DATE(timestampColumn)
```